# Xamarin - using android native library

Tags: android, xamarin, native

I have good working Android Studio java application which use third-party .so libraries and I need to transfer part of it into Xamarin Forms project.

Configuration in java application is as follow:

```
public interface dataWork
{
    int getType(byte[] bArr);
    void initialize(Object obj);
}
```

then:

```
final class dataWorkFinal implements dataWork
{
    private final int parserType;
    private native int getType(int i, byte[] bArr);
    public native void initialize(Object obj);

    static 
    {
        System.loadLibrary("workLibrary");
    }

    dataWorkFinal (int i) { this.parserType = i; }

    public int getType(byte[] bArr) {
        return getType(this.parserType, bArr);
    }
}
```

then in main section:

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
dataWorkFinal work = new dataWorkFinal (12345);
work.initialize(context);

byte[] bDat1 = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03}; 
int res = work.getType(bDat1);
```

in Xamarin Forms (Android):

loading .so library with DLLimport working OK.
finding function inside library - OK.
Error - when funcion is invoked - Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1

Current Xamarin:

```
[DllImport("workLibrary", EntryPoint = "getType")]
public static extern int getType(int i, int j);

....
byte[] bDat1 = new byte[] { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03};
int ms = getType( 12345, bDat1);
```

Need some help/ideas how to solve it?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/native-libraries